# I am not able to understand how the output of the program is 3

Tags: python

```
 num = 0
 for i in range(5,0,-1):
      num+= i > num

 print(num)
```

When I ran the program it was displaying the output as 3. I am not able to understand how 3 is the output

Comment: Have you tried to [debug your code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)? Have you found a particular operation that hasn’t meeted your expectation?

Comment: Add `print(num)` inside your loop and things should become clearer.

Answer (score 4):

```
 num = 0
 for i in range(5,0,-1):  #Loop  5 to 1
      num+= i > num       # for first 3 steps ( i > num) = True = 1, i.e add 1 to num
                          # for remaining steps (i > num) = False = 0, i.e add 0 to num
      print(i,num)

 print(num)
```

output

```
5 1
4 2
3 3
2 3
1 3

3
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at what happens inside the loop:

```
num = 0
for i in range(5,0,-1):
    print(f'num:{num}, i:{i}, i>num:{i>num} >>> num+(i>num):{num}+{i>num}', end='=')
    num+= i > num
    print(f'{num}')
#print(num)
```

Output:

```
num:0, i:5, i>num:True >>> num+(i>num):0+True=1
num:1, i:4, i>num:True >>> num+(i>num):1+True=2
num:2, i:3, i>num:True >>> num+(i>num):2+True=3
num:3, i:2, i>num:False >>> num+(i>num):3+False=3
num:3, i:1, i>num:False >>> num+(i>num):3+False=3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot now it is clear. I tried by giving print inside the loop even then it was not clear.

Answer (score 1):

you are checking the condition `if i > num` every time you increment. Here, you are not incrementing `i`, instead the condition `i>num` , which return True when `i> num` and increment `1` each time the condition is True.

Answer (score 1):

you add to num the boolean value of `i > num`. in python, True is 1 and False is 0.

if you follow this logic you will see that the expression returns 1 3 times

Answer (score 0):

```
num = 0
for i in range(5,0,-1):
    num+= i > num #  this line similar to num = num + (i > num)
print(num)
```

if `i > num` yeilds to `True` then it is equal to 1 so, then`num = num + 1`
else `i > num` yeilds to `False` then it is equal to 0 so, then `num = num + 0`

Answer (score 0):

The result of the relation (i > num) evaluated to 0/1 (True/False). Adding print to the body of the loop it may be clearer for you:

```
num = 0
for i in range(5,0,-1):
    num+= i > num
    print("i: {}, num: {}".format(i, num))

print(num)
```

And the output:

```
i: 5, num: 1
i: 4, num: 2
i: 3, num: 3
i: 2, num: 3
i: 1, num: 3
3
```

Answer (score 0):

This loop will execute for 5 times .And i 's value will be "5 4 3 2 1"

i > num will  producre , boolean values. when True it will be treated as 1 and when False 0.

So you will get 3 "True" values and 2 "False" values .Hence result is 3, which is outputed.